# JHipster: Remember Me with oauth

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, yeoman-generator, jhipster

I am new to JHipster. I have started working on a project that was created using JHipster. It is using OAuth2. I would like to add the remember-me functionality to it. I added this to the security config:

```
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
```

I am using the remember-me implementation provided [here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/security/CustomPersistentRememberMeServices.java). I have created the table for persistent token but I still get the session timeout to be 1800 seconds in the 'AuthServerProvider'.

Am I even moving in the right direction? Is this even applicable in the case of OAuth? What do I need to do to get remember-me to work? Please advise!

Comment: Just a note that this question is not specific to Yeoman/JHipster. You may want to tag the java framework you're using for OAuth as you'll have way more answer asking about specific resource.

Comment: Hi, did you finally managed to find a solution?